# offcanvas/sidebar css transition not working in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm trying to make an offcanvas/sidebar with react,CSS, javascript. its my first time building sidebar with css/javascript. I've applied the transition css code but its not working and I don't know why. I've a offcanvas class and I'm adding .open class when the off canvas toggle state is true and in the css, first i've added the transition property in .offcanvas class then, I've added the transform property in .offcanvas.open
Please help me do the transition 
Heres my jsx:

```
  <div className="offcanvasWrapper">
  {/* canvas */}
  <div className={`offcanvas ${show ? "open" : ""}`}>
    <div className="d-flex offcanvas_topRow justify-content-between align-items-center ">
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        size="lg"
        onClick={handleClose}
        icon={faTimes}
        color="#000"
      />
      <p onClick={viewcareerPage} className="mb-0">
        {job.company_name}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className="offcanvas_jobTitle text-center">
      <Image
        src={job.company_logo}
        className="mb-3"
        onError={(e) => {
          e.target.src = companyDefaultlogo;
        }}
        fluid
      />
      <h2>{job.job_title}</h2>
      <p>{job.job_location}</p>
    </div>
    <div
      className="d-flex
       justify-content-end align-items-center text-primary pr-4 copyLink "
      onClick={copyLink}
    >
      <img src={Clipboard} className="img-fluid" alt="copy_link" />
      <span>Copy Link</span>
    </div>

    <div className="offcanvas_jobInfo">
      <div className="offcanvas_jobInfo_detail ">
        <p className="mb-2">Job Type</p>
        <span>{job.job_type}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="offcanvas_jobInfo_detail ">
        <p className="mb-2">Location</p>
        <span>{jobLocationHumanizer()}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="offcanvas_jobInfo_detail ">
        <p className="mb-2">Deadline</p>
        <span>{s}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="offcanvas_jobInfo_detail">
        <p className="mb-2">Salary Range</p>
        <span>{getSalaryRange()} </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="offcanvas_jobDetails">
      <h4>Job Description</h4>
      <p className="mb-4">{job.job_description}</p>
      <h4>Job Responsibilities</h4>
      <p className="mb-4">{job.job_responsibities}</p>
      <h4>Benefits</h4>
      <p className="mb-4">{job.benifits}</p>
    </div>

    <div className="d-flex flex-column mt-3 justify-content-end align-items-end">
      <Button onClick={apply} className="btn offcanvas_btn">
        Apply
      </Button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {/* shadow */}
  <div onClick={handleClose} className={`overlay ${show ? "open" : ""}`} />
</div>
```

Heres the css:

```
 .offcanvasWrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}
.offcanvas {
  background: #ffffff;
  flex: 0.4;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transform: translateX(320px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.offcanvas.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.offcanvas_topRow {
  padding: 30px;
}
.offcanvas_topRow p {
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  color: #1565d8;
}

.offcanvas_jobTitle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 30px;
}
.offcanvas_jobTitle img {
  height: 100px;
}
.offcanvas_jobTitle h2 {
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  color: #183b56;
}
.offcanvas_jobTitle p {
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #183b56;
}

.offcanvas_jobInfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 623px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
}
.offcanvas_jobInfo_detail {
  width: max-content;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.offcanvas_jobInfo_detail p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #183b56;
}
.offcanvas_jobInfo_detail span {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #5a7184;
}

.offcanvas_jobDetails {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.offcanvas_jobDetails h4 {
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  color: #183b56;
}

.offcanvas_jobDetails::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 8px;
}

.offcanvas_jobDetails::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #3c9f86;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 103px;
}

.offcanvas_jobDetails p {
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #183b56;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.offcanvas_btn {
  background: #3c9f86;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 434px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none !important;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0;
  background-color: #183b5669;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease 0.1s;
  flex: 0;
}
.overlay.open {
  opacity: 3;
  flex: 0.6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.copyLink img {
  height: 16px;
}
.copyLink span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to see the whole context of what is happening in your code. Could be the "show" state. Also could be your CSS, which looks a little complex. I've taken your off canvas and offcanvas.open css classes and managed to get them working fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-drake-ely0n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @mando i just your code but mine is different, can u plz use the same jsx and css and make it work, or u can modify the jsx and css then make it work. I've tried many times but couldnt make I work, just need to make a offcanvas,sidebar

Comment: I can’t really replicate your code since there are a lot of things missing - Eg FontAwesome, variables, and even some css classes in your markup aren’t in your css, so I can’t know what they’re doing. You need to provide more code or even better a working example in codesandbox